# ActionBarDrawerToggle is being shown only while swiping(moving) drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout, drawertoggle

I have problem with drawer indicator in toolbar.
The icon (hamburger) is visible only while moving (swiping) drawer view, and becomes invisible on stop.
Here is screenshot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4ihv.jpg

And while moving it becomes visible

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOTLG.jpg

If stop move drawer view it becomes invisible again.

Here is my setup code

```
    mToolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mToolbar.setTitle(getToolbarTitle());
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    if (hasDrawerToggle()) {
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerMainLayout,
                R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);
        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        mDrawerMainLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }



@Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        if (hasDrawerToggle()) {
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    }

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (hasDrawerToggle()) {
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using hasDrawerToggle() condition?

The problem may due to your condition, so try by removing condition from all places like onPostCreate,onCreate etc.

Hop it will work.

Comment: In inherited activity.

Comment: I have tried to use without this condition check, but still doesn't work